# Returning the result of a function call with/without parentheses

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Why is there a difference in the return values of F and G in the following code?

```
Function F {
    Return (New-Object Collections.Generic.LinkedList[Object])
}

Function G {
    Return New-Object Collections.Generic.LinkedList[Object]
}

Function Write-Type($x) {
    If($null -eq $x) {
        Write-Host "null"
    } Else {
        Write-Host $x.GetType()
    }
}

Write-Type (F) # -> null
Write-Type (G) # -> System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1[System.Object]
```

As far as I understand, if a function returns some kind of empty collection, PowerShell will "unwrap" it into null, and so F does what I expect. But what's going on with G?

Edit: As pointed out by JPBlanc, only PowerShell 3.0 exhibits this difference. In 2.0, both lines print `null`. What changed?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I  don't read correctly your question, as F is afunction you are using () to evaluate the function. So then the result of `Write-Type` function is the same for me in PowerShell V2.0.

So, In PowerShell 3.0 I meet your problem.

Now using :

```
Trace-Command -name TypeConversion -Expression {Write-Type (F)} -PSHost
```

Versus

```
Trace-Command -name TypeConversion -Expression {Write-Type (G)} -PSHost
```

as far as I understand the () before before returning object generate the following

```
 Converting "Collections.Generic.LinkedList" to "System.Type".
     Conversion to System.Type
         Conversion to System.Type
             Could not find a match for "System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList".
         Could not find a match for "Collections.Generic.LinkedList".
 Converting "Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1" to "System.Type".
     Conversion to System.Type
         Conversion to System.Type
             Found "System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1[T]" in the loaded assemblies.
 Converting "Object" to "System.Type".
     Conversion to System.Type
         Conversion to System.Type
             Found "System.Object" in the loaded assemblies.
```

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. In `Write-Type F`, the `F` will be interpreted as the string `"F"`, which is not what I want.

Comment: not exactly, @JPBlanc is actually right, you should not put function arguments inside brackets. However I could not find explanation why. Is this just a language design or brackets does something special. In order for F to be treated as string you would have to surround it with quotation marks. So F is an object and "F" is a string.

Comment: I recommend you try this yourself. `Write-Type F` and `Write-Type G` will both print `System.String`. What I am doing here is not "putting function arguments inside brackets", but rather calling the function `F` and passing its return value as a parameter to `Write-Type`.

Comment: Ok, when JPBlanc answered, I tried to search for explanation why you should not use brackets around function parameters and all I could find was only this information, no explanation. Indeed it seems to work. But I'm not sure everyone is saying this is forbidden without a reason.

Comment: @SzymonKuzniak Parens *are not* used for function arguments in PowerShell. Period. If it's working right now, it's not by design and it may stop working in a future release. See http://huddledmasses.org/parenthesis-in-powershell/ and http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2008/08/19/calling-powershell-functions-with-parameters.aspx

Comment: It's not forbidden, it just means something different than in C-like languages. In PowerShell, `Write-Type (F)` is equivalent to `$f_result = F; Write-Type $f_result`.

Comment: I've edited the question to note the discrepancy between 2.0 and 3.0. Good catch!

Comment: I could reproduce the behavior as well. In PowerShell v2 you get the same return value for both functions (`$null` when using `return` and a `LinkedList` object when not using `return`). It's only in v3 that you get a different return value when not using a variable or subexpression. I'd consider this a bug.

Comment: Have a look to the difference in `Trace-Command` result for both F and G, you perhaps have more informations. I'an not sure to understand.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Powershell function, what "return" does is exiting from function early.

I checked Bruce P's book "Powershell in action" page 262, it says:

**"So why,then, does Powershell need a return statement? The answer is, flow control. Sometimes you want to exit a function early. Without a return statement, you'd have to write complex conditional statements to get the flow control to reach the end..."**

Also Keith Hill has a very good blog talking about this: http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/effective-powershell-item-7-understanding-output/

**"......"return $Proc" does *not* mean that the functions only output is the contents of the $Proc variable.  In fact this construct is semantically equivalent to "$Proc; return". ....."**

Based on this, if you change your function code like this, the script output are the same:

```
Function F {
    (New-Object Collections.Generic.LinkedList[Object])
    Return 
}

Function G {
   New-Object Collections.Generic.LinkedList[Object]
    Return 
}
```

This behavior is different than traditional language so it causes some confusions.

Comment: As stated in my comment to C.B.'s answer, the issue is unrelated to the `return` keyword. It's an issue that apparently was introduced with PowerShell v3.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. I did not see the hidden comment when posted this.